# Python Private Blockchain proof of work

Tags: python, blockchain

Currently I've found a python PoW for blockchain. The problem is that I'm trying to associate all this information with my business. Currently I own a mobile wallet. And users need to make deposits to my bank account. but I don't want to have a Centralized Database instead use BlockChain concept and reward users with local currency when they mine transactions. there are many doubts rising as I write this.

- How Can I still hold the deposits, withdrawls to their wallets and be able to share a % with miners a fee when they execute a block verification?

Example.

```
1 Alice deposits to Business bank account 100 USD
2 Company checks deposit and approves 100 USD on their wallet
3 Alice pays Bob 10 USD (Company takes 0.10 USD and Miner 0.5 USD)
4 Bob Withdrawls 40 USD
5 Company deposits money to Bob's Bank Account.
```

Comment: If you're a single company, why would you want a distributed database with people mining? My question is probably naive since I'm not familiar with all the ideas involved in cryptocurrencies. This is just curiosity.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Because that way we can prevent hackers from doing wrong things. also for Atomicity of Data...???

Comment: I'm not sure how this prevents "hackers". The security of the Bitcoin blockchain comes from the massive amounts of computation that have gone into building it. If you don't have that, a centralised database with some checksumming for integrity would work just as fine (or so it seems to me).

Comment: As for atomicity, if I understand what you intend, you can just use a database. MVCC is taken care of by transactions so you won't have a problem.

Comment: Can you give details of the python PoW for blockchain you have mentioned. Are there examples where it is used currently?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim The blockchain concept prevents people from corrupting the data, also the data its inmutable. And can be self regulated in terms that it saves data on blocks and all blocks relate to the earlies block that's what it is called blockchain. and has been used as a decentrilized database. And Yes I see this is the future and I want to implement it but just need a clearance on this specific example. BTW the code im unsing is this. https://github.com/dvf/blockchain